# IE8 / jQuery - fadeIn not displaying absolutely-positioned child element outside boundaries of faded-in parent

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I've been banging my head against this for a couple of days, and I give up.

I have a div, containing a .hover target, and a div to display once that target is hovered. That child div consists of a span and a paragraph, with the span absolutely-positioned to be partly outside of the div.

In modern browsers, it all fades in together nicely, but in IE <8 the span (red background) does not correctly fade in, only showing the part inside the parent div, and only once the animation has completed does the rest appear outside.

I've tried using different jQuery selectors, written custom fade functions to remove filters, absolutely positioned a parent element off-screen in an attempt to force the browser not to use DirectX, and so on.

JSBin showing the problem (IE8 or lower only):
http://jsbin.com/emegas/3/edit

HTML:

```
<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="pointer">hover here</span>
  <div class="tip">
    <span class="tipPointer"></span>
    <p>asdasdas.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.pointer').hover(function(){
    $(this).next('.tooltip .tip').stop(true, true).fadeIn(1000);
}, function(){
    $(this).next('.tooltip .tip').stop(true, true).hide();
});
```

How, if it's possible, can I get the span to fade in simultaneously with the parent?

Answer (score 0):

Works great in IE7 and IE8 here. Only problem I could think of is some overflow bug with your version of IE8. Try to add overflow:visible; to both your elements in CSS.

Comment: Thanks, but no joy (overflow:visible; is in my dev code but I removed it for the test case) - I've confirmed it on another two XP boxes, all are on 8.00.6001.18702. At least it works somewhere, I guess :)

Comment: not sure what you mean by XP boxes. But it might be only a problem with IE on Win XP then. My IE10 in IE8 mode shows the same results as chrome and ff. Sorry I can't help you any further since I have no win XP.